# Print an element of 2D array of character or string?

Tags: c

```
main()
{
    char str[][3]={"ab","cd","ef","gh"};
    printf("\n%s\n%s",str[2][0],&str[0][0]);
//WHY WE NEED TO PUT "&" TO PRINT &str[2][0] the element.
}
```

//while this works properly

```
main()
{
    char str[][3]={"ab","cd","ef","gh"};
    printf("\n%s\n%s",str[2],&str[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

str[2] is the third element of array `str`. It is in turn a character array that has type `char[3]`. In function call like this

```
printf( "%s", str[2] );
```

the array is converted to pointer to its first character (element). The first character of array `str[2]` can be gotten like `str[2][0]`. So its address is determined like `&str[2][0]`.

Thus expressions `str[2]` and `&str[2][0]` are equivalent.

As for this call

```
printf("\n%s\n%s",str[2],&str[0]);
```

then it is invalid. Format specifier `%s` expects an argument of type `char *` while the type of expression `&str[0]` is `char **`. However because in any case expression `&str[0]` has the value that is the address of the first element of array `str[0]` the function produces the correct result.

If you want to ouput only a single character instead of a string you have to use format specifier `%c` For example

```
printf("\n%c\n%s",str[2][0],&str[0][0]);
          ^^^
```

In this function call as `str[2][0]` is a single character then there is used format specifier %c for its output.

Comment: @Abhishek Sharma We can print symbol str[2][0] but as it has type char (it is one character) we have to use format specifier %c instead of %s because format specifier %s expects a pointer to character instead of a single chracter

Comment: thanks for reply..i am a beginner in programming. yes u r ri8.